# multiple Jquery conflict issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am using multiple jquery libraries in my website.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery_1_11_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/legalzoom-marketplace/js/touch.js"></script>
```

I use Jquery 1.7.2 to make Jquery sortable work for mobile as per [this](http://touchpunch.furf.com/). Because of this my bootstrap JS is not working, I have added the below code to remove make bootstrap work.

`var jQuery_1_11_3 = $.noConflict(true);`

and I am trying to show modal using

`jQuery_1_11_3('.modal').modal('show')`

but it doesn't seem to work. It throws the error below `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher.` Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to use "jQuery UI Touch Punch", because it is the only jQuery touch library out there ... ?

Comment: I am using jQuery touch library

Comment: Whoever has put a -1 for this question, Please tell me why did you mark it as in appropriate?

Comment: @noc2spamツ Could you read out the question properly? I am using Jquery1.7.2 to make Jquery sortable work. and bootstrap requires jquery 1.9.1 or latest. If this makes sense please remove your negative vote.

Comment: noc2spamツ I guess http://touchpunch.furf.com/ is the only available plugin to make the Jquery draggable work for mobiles.

Comment: Not sure. If this is the case, then I would have custom made something for myself. Anyway, to help you with the question... Try assigning `jQuery.noConflict()`  instead of `$.noConflict()`. Should help.

Comment: I withdrew my negvote. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You must agree that You're doing wrong. Better to find and fix issue, than play with 2 big libraries. 
I'm not sure but hope it helps:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var jQuery_1_7_2 = $.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var jQuery_1_11_3 = $.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function(){
           // some other operations
        });
    }(jQuery_1_7_2));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function(){
           $('.modal').modal('show');
        });
    }(jQuery_1_11_3));
</script>
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: What is the use of this? IIFE and passing the jQuery object? thanks!

Comment: I'm passing $ definition to another variable (jQuery_1_11_3 = $.noConflict(true);) and then wrapping with closure and passing jQuery_versioned_variable to closure.